# Using same ivy-settings.xml in Eclipse with IvyDE for the ant task

Tags: eclipse, ivy

I'm using Eclipse Kepler with IvyDE. I have setup the Ivy settings path in Eclipse (Window -> Preferences -> Ivy -> Settings) to my settings file (http://myserver.com/ivy-settings.xml). It works fine. But I also use some Ant scripts inside Eclipse, and I need those scripts to access the repository. In order to do that I have needed to call the following task in my Ant script

```
<ivy:settings url="http://myserver.com/ivy-settings.xml"/>
```

Is there anyway I can remove that hardcoded url, and point the settings to use the same URL used by IvyDE?

Thanks

Comment: Environment variable?

Comment: I tried to create a String substitution ivy_settings_xml_url with value http://myserver.com/ivy-settings.xml, and use ${ivy_settings_xml_url} as the ivy_settings path, but I got an error saying "The Ivy settings file 'file:/C:/eclipse-kepler/http:/vulcan/ivy-settings.xml' cannot be found", so it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually there is an easy way to do it. You just need to define the String substitution (go to Window -> Preferences -> Ivy -> Settings -> Variables -> Edit Variables -> New; create a new variable **ivy_settings_xml_url** pointing to your **ivy-settings.xml**) and put **${ivy_settings_xml_url}** as the Ivy settings path). Then, go to Window -> Preferences -> Ant -> Runtime -> Properties and add a new property **ivy_settings_xml_url** with value **${ivy_settings_xml_url}**. Now you can use **${ivy_settings_xml_url}** in your ant script:

```
<ivy:settings url="${ivy_settings_xml_url}"/>
```